# htaccess se regenera automáticamente

Tags: apache2

Hace un tiempo que trabajo con una tienda en Prestashop con la cual trabajo con URLs amigables, el tema está que ayer detectamos que no funcionaba y al entrar al server detecté carpetas extrañas, por lo que restauré ficheros a una versión que aparentemente estaba limpia y actualicé a la última versión de Prestashop, con su cambio de plantilla puesto que la anterior no es compatible, hasta aquí todo correcto.
La cuestión es que me encuentro con que el ".htaccess" se regenera solo con el siguiente contenido:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

El propietario y grupo son el de la carpeta, con permisos 444, con lo que no me permite colocar las URLs amigables ni ninguna otra sentencia, he provado modificandole los permisos y propietario, pero no hay manera de hacerlo funcionar ¿alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano